# How to set private class to form validation callback in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Suppose this is my controller. (copied from CI documentation)

```
<?php

class Form extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|is_unique[users.email]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('myform');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('formsuccess');
        }
    }

    public function username_check($str)
    {
        if ($str == 'test')
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The %s field can not be the word "test"');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

But **username_check($str)**  function is public. According to CI documentation if i want to make a private method I need to add **"_"** like this.

```
private function _utility()
{
  // some code
}
```

But how can I set username_check() as private and callback from form validation set_rules?

Should i use DOUBLE underscore **"__"**  i.e **callback__username_check**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just declare your private function as you have already done:

```
function _username_check()
{
  // some code
}
```

And in the validation rule, use:

```
callback__username_check
```

As I have seen, this must work just fine!

**Remember:**

The `_` prefix would take care of your function privacy, so you do not really have to use the keyword `private` to declare the function to let the `form_validation` class access to that function!

Comment: yah i know that. I have checked that the double __ (underscore) works fine. Thanks for you answer.